# Is it necessary to print the Egypt e-visa?

Tags: visas, egypt, toronto, yyz

Im flying from Toronto to Egypt. I got an e-visa but forgot to print it. I'm at the airport already. Can I print it here somewhere? Is showing it on my phone enough? What are my alternatives?

I've seen some articles describing eprint printers and apps from HP, eprintit, and St Joseph Communications allowing one to print from a mobile phone at the YYZ airport, but none of their apps seem to show an option for YYZ as of 2020. Are those printers still working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Egyptian Government's [e-Visa portal](https://visa2egypt.gov.eg/eVisa/FAQ), under "What is an e-Visa" says this:

> The link to download your e-Visa will be emailed to you. Passport control officers at ports of entry can verify your e-Visa on their system.

Further down the same page, under "Requirements," this appears:

> Entry requirements (on arrival)
>
> - Passport valid for at least six months from arrival date
> - e-Visa printout

Thus, you should carry a physical printout of the e-Visa. Given the clear statement that a printout is required, it's likely you'll be denied entry without it.

The second part of your question is how to get a printout when you're already at the departure airport. I'm sorry I cannot help with that. I'd start at the airline ticket counter, or the airport information kiosk, or see if there's an airport business center.

Note too that depending upon what country's passport you carry, you may be eligible to apply for a visa upon your arrival in Egypt.

Comment: @Crazydre That can't be right, the default is a visa upon landing

Comment: @personjerry Apologies, had completely forgotten that fact. I take back everything